# How can I initialize DataContext with a View Model if the constructor is parameterized?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have recently parameterized my xViewModel's constructor.
Before that, I was doing this in my window:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:xViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Now I have two parameters :

```
using Prism.Services.Dialogs;
using Prism.Regions;
.
.
.
protected readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager; 
public xViewModel(
            IDialogService dialogService,
            IRegionManager regionManager)
{
_dialogService = dialogService;
_regionManager = regionManager;
}
```

How can I instantiate DataContext with my xViewModel?

Comment: In code behind instead of XAML, e.g. in the Window's constructor: `DataContext = new xViewModel(dialogService, regionManager);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ViewModelLocator`](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/viewmodel-locator.html) to wire the `DataContext` of a view to an instance of a view model using a standard naming convention:

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.Views.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this in without or with Prism.

- You can instantiate all classes in the code-behind constructor of the `Window`, pass the dependencies as parameters to the window when it is instantiated or assign the view model from outside to the `DataContext` property of the window.

  ```
  public MyWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      // ...instantiate the dialog service and region manager
      DataContext = xViewModel(dialogService, regionManager);
  }
  ```
- Prism can make this a lot easier, if you use one of its [supported dependency injection containers](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Managing-Dependencies.html). Then you can use the container to resolve an instance of your view model and it will automatically inject all dependencies like `IDialogService` and `IRegionManager` into its constructor.

  In the code-behind contructor, resolve an instance of your `xViewModel` using `IContainerExtension`

  ```
  public MyWindow(IContainerExtension containerExtension)
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = containerExtension.Resolve<xViewModel>();
  }
  ```
- If you use the built-in `ViewModelLocator`, Prism will automatically resolve an instance of the view model for a view and assign it as `DataContext` if you follow its [naming convention](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/viewmodel-locator.html). All you have to do is set the `AutoWireViewModel` attached property to `True` in you view.

  ```
  <Window x:Class="Demo.Views.MainWindow"
          xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
          prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
  ```

  Read more about the `ViewModelLocator`, customization and examples in the [documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/viewmodel-locator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set it in code behind instead of XAML:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // add code to initialize the dialogService and regionManager variables

    DataContext = new xViewModel(dialogService, regionManager);
}
```